Using JavaScript template literals `${...}` does not seem to work when using JSP instead of HTML, it returns null in servlet
Im trying to make an AJAX call to a servlet from a login page which is designed as a '.jsp' page.
Im using 'fetch' API for AJAX (code snippet attached below). This script is written in same '.jsp' page below <body>.
/* Function for making Ajax call to login controller */
    const fnAjaxUsersController = function () {
        const userName = document.getElementById('idUserName');
        const userPassWord = document.getElementById('idUserPassWord');

        console.log(userName.value);
        console.log(userPassWord.value);

        const myHeaders = new Headers();
        myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

        const linkToLoginController = `UsersController.do`;

        fetch(linkToLoginController, {      
            method: 'POST'  ,
            headers: myHeaders,         
            body: `uname=${userName.value}&pwd=${userPassWord.value}`            
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error(`${linkToLoginController} response failed`);
                } else {
                    console.log(response);
                    return response.json()
                }
            })
            .then((jsonData) => {
                console.log(jsonData);
                if (Number.parseInt(jsonData.msgCode) === 0) {
                    fnChangeClassToInValid(userName);
                    fnChangeClassToInValid(userPassWord);

                } else {
                    fnChangeClassToValid(userName);
                    fnChangeClassToValid(userPassWord);

                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(`${err.message}`)
            }).finally(() => {
                //console.log(`This block is always executed`);
                /* Normally used for disappearing loading buffer */
            });
    };

Now the request is getting through the servlet controller but when I'm accessing them using getParameter method its showing null.
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        /*
         * Creating user object(No need to validate parameters as they are handled at
         * front end)
         */     
        Users u = new Users((String)request.getParameter("uname"), (String)request.getParameter("pwd"));
        System.out.println(u);

.....   

Im guessing it has something to do with Content-Type header as same is working if login page is changed to plain '.html'.
Below is the form for accepting user inputs.
    <form id ="idLoginForm" accept-charset="utf-8" method='post' action='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/header/header.jsp'>
        <div class="row mb-3 text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col">
                <img class="mt-4" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/img/80_ISG.png" alt="" width="100" height="57">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-3 text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col">
                <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Please sign in</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-3 ">
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="idUserName" placeholder="Username"
                        aria-describedby="idUserNameFeedBack" required> <label for="idUserName">Username</label>
                    <div id="idUserNameFeedBack" class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please enter valid user name
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-3 ">
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col">
                <div class="form-floating">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="idUserPassWord" placeholder="Password"
                        aria-describedby="idUserPassWordFeedBack" required> <label
                        for="idUserPassWord">Password</label>
                    <div id="idUserPassWordFeedBack" class="invalid-feedback">
                        Please enter valid user password
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="row mb-3 text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 themed-grid-col">
                <button id="idLoginSubmit" class="btn btn-primary w-100 py-2" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-body-secondary">© 2017–2024</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 ">
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


OK so userName and Password are populated through a form and this 'fetch' Ajax call is triggered via click event attached to submit button with prevent default option. Im accessing these parameters in servlet referred as 'UsersController.do'

You know whats weird here. I tried printing uname=${userName.value}&pwd=${userPassWord.value}  after storing ethem in a string and its showing null

I have updated the original post


Im guessing it has something to do with Content-Type header as same is working if login page is changed to plain '.html'.

It's because the JavaScript template literal syntax ${...} is also interpreted by JSP as part of Expression Language.
You have 2 options:

Put JS code in its own JS file and reference it by <script src="yourScriptFile.js">. Additional benefit is that it can improve performance, because client can now request it asynchronously and also has the possibility to cache it following different rules.
Escape the template literals which you don't want to be processed as part of JSP EL. You can do so by putting a backslash in the front of $ as in  \${...}.


Actually I got it after doing some trial and error and was about to type the answer but thanks man issue was exactly as you explained it in detail and this was my very first experience with Stack Overflow. Thank you very much. Happy coding.
